# images in Collection View are bad quality

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a collection view with a bunch of images in it but the problem is that the images are very blurry and pixelated in the collection view. When I select one of the pictures, it shows a larger picture that makes it good enough quality to see. So I'm guessing its the scaling of the picture into a small cell that makes it bad quality in the collection view. How do I go about fixing the images so they don't look blurry/bad quality in the collection view?

The actual picture's size 640x853 and the cell size is 100x133.
this is what I have:

```
 UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];



                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake( cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height));
                [theImage drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
                UIImage *small = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            UIImageView *cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:small];
                            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImageView];
```

Comment: Which mode did you setup for the imageView?

Comment: What do you mean by mode? @Matz

Comment: Hi, I mean the contentMode from UIImageView

Comment: I updated the code I have so far in the question @Matz